# Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, arrays, macros

```
#define L 1
#define M L+1

int main(void){

    int N=L*M*2;
    char s [N]={'1','2'};
    printf("%d", sizeof(s));

    return 1;   
}
```

Why does the above code cannot be compiled? The compiler of Eclipse says two things:

1. *Variable-sized object may not be initialized:* Is because the definition of N with M and L at the macro  or is it because I can't initialize an array with *type* arr[x] where x is variable under any circumstances?
2. *excess elements in array initializer*- What does it mean?

Comment: Ask yourself what would happen if `N` and the number of elements in your initializer would not agree with each other?

Comment: Incidentally, `L*M*2 == L*L+1*2 == 1*1+1*2 == 3`. Not your main issue, but I thought you should know.

Comment: Are you aware that N = 1 * 1 + 1 * 2 = 3? (Because you didn't parenthesize the replacement text of the M macro).

Comment: @Jens: Yeah, I'm aware to that, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because I can't initialize an array with type arr[x] where x is variable?

Indeed, pre-C99, the array size must be a *constant expression*.  In C99, this has been relaxed with *variable-length arrays*.

(This is is nothing to do with macros.)

> excess elements in array initializer- What does it mean?

Fix the first problem, and this should go away.

Answer (score 1):

The array size in your example is specified by `N`, which is not a constant. This means that your array is VLA (variable-length array). C language does not allow initializers in VLA declarations.

In order for that to compile, `N` has to me made into a constant (since `M` and `L` are constants, `N` can also be a constant). Either declare `N` using `#define` or as a enum member.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly,

```
char s [N]={'1','2'};
```

N needs to be a constant