# what is "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to fill an array with numbers from 1-100 with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[100];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int num[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
c:18:13: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

I'm still relatively new to programming so I'm not sure what this means. Can you tell me?

Comment: Being new to programming doesn't mean you can skip searching the internet before asking. Stackoverflow itself suggests taking a look at the [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11562642/912144), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3082914/912144) and many others answering your question.

Answer (score 4):

Replace this

```
 int num[i] = i+1;
```

For this:

```
 num[i] = i+1;
```

You already declare the array on the top `int num[100];`

First you declare the array, and then you iterate over it inside the loop.

Since you are new, it is preferable you start by reading a good book about the subject my [recommendation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672305100).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `int` in `int num[i] = i+1`. The compiler thinks you're trying to declare a new array (also called `num`) with `i` elements in it (that's the *variable-sized object* part). Just remove the `int` from that line.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the array again in the loop:

```
int num[i] = i+1;
```

Anyway, this is the error in your code but the problem for the compiler is not there: it gives you that error because that's not a valid declaration with initialization for an array. If you just write `int num[i];` the code it's valid code and it will compile without error (well, only from C99, old C89 doesn't support *variable-length arrays*). This is what the compiler recognizes and tries to report.